# How to redirect back to previous page after login in Code Igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Okay, so this is what I do:

1. I go to `www.mywebsite.com/orders?id=1`
2. It redirects be to login before proceeding.
3. I log in successfully but it redirects to `www.mywebsite.com/orders`.

If I am already logged in and go directly using GET method, it works fine. But if I am asked to login, the GET method disappears.

How do I preserve `?id=1`?

Comment: Store it in a session variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before redirecting the user back to the login page store the current page (the requested page) in a session variable. Assuming you have a function called `check_login` this would more or less look like what you should do:

```
public function check_login() {
    if (!$this->session->has_userdata('logged_in') || $this->session->logged_in !== true) {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
            $uri = uri_string() . '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        } else {
            $uri = uri_string();
        }
        $this->session->set_userdata('redirect', $uri);
        redirect('/auth/login');
    }
}
```

Then when the user successfully logs in your login function should somewhere have the following logic:

```
public function login() {

    // form validation
    // get post vars
    // check username/pwd against db
    if ($login) {

        if ($this->session->has_userdata('redirect')) {
            redirect($this->session->redirect);
        } else {
            redirect('/dashboard');
        }

    } else {
        // error logging in
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

session variable could store the id.While log in using session pass the id value.You can retrive the value anywhere in session.

$this->load->library('session');
$this->session->set_userdata('userId', 'YourId');

where userId would be the name of the session variable, and YourId would be the value.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use this
redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

Comment: it may be helpful to expand on your answer a bit. Perhaps use an example. Additionally asking follow up questions about the environment. The redirect could be happening in code or on the server for instance. Looks like youre on the right track though